# What are command primaries?

Tags: command-line, posix, arguments

I came across the notion of primaries from running `man find`:

```
.
.
.
PRIMARIES
     All primaries which take a numeric argument allow the number to be preceded by a plus sign (``+'') or a minus sign (``-'').  A preceding plus sign means ``more than n'', a pre-
     ceding minus sign means ``less than n'' and neither means ``exactly n''.
.
.
     -depth n
             True if the depth of the file relative to the starting point of the traversal is n.
```

Searching [POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) for "primaries" turned up no results.

Doing a little bit of exploring, it looks like primaries are different from switches and flags because they appear after the switches, flags, and main arguments:

```
$ find -depth 1 .
find: illegal option -- e
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
$ find . -depth 1
./.DS_Store
./.vagrant
./foo
./some
```

I'm wondering:

- What are primaries?
- Is there any documentation I can read about them?
- How are they different from switches or flags?

Comment: Related: [What is the definition of a primary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254410)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're the conditions/actions of `find`'s language, the ones that the "expression" referred to in the usage line mainly consists of:  `-name`, `-type`, `-print`, `-exec` etc. The term is used to separate them from the operators that only combine the primaries: `!`, `-a`, `-o` and the parenthesis.

I don't remember seeing that term used in other contexts than `find`. It's used in the [POSIX specification for `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) and in the [FreeBSD man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)). GNU stands out in this, too, the documentation for GNU find ([e.g. the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)) doesn't use the term, but instead divides the primaries to *tests* about the properties of the files, *actions* that do something, and *options* that affect how `find` itself works. The division seems helpful but is slightly inaccurate, since all primaries return a truth value, even the actions.

Comment: From [man7](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) it looks like in GNU they are "GLOBAL OPTIONS", is this true?

Comment: Right, it uses that term too for those primaries that change how `find` itself works.